# git submodules foreach does not have $sm_path defined in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

I am trying to run a Jenkins scripts that basically zip up submodules if it's detected a merge into the primary branch.

The problem I am having is that when I run

```
git submodule foreach 'echo $sm_path' | xargs zip -r fabric-${NEXT_VERSION}
```

`sm_path` is clearly not defined, but those results are passed to xargs/zip and there are no args. When I run it locally, all is well.

Can someone explain to me what's going on? Below is my error and pipeline

```
+ git submodule foreach --quiet 'echo $sm_path'
+ xargs zip -r fabric-1.0.2

zip error: Nothing to do! (fabric-1.0.2)
```

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        kubernetes {
            yamlFile 'pod.yaml'
        }
    }
    environment {
        NEXT_VERSION = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git tag --sort=committerdate | tail -1 | awk -F \'.\' \'{print $1"."$2"." $3 +1}\'').trim()
    }
    stages {

        stage('Determine merge status') {
            when {
                expression {
                    env.STATE == 'merged' && env.TARGET_BRANCH == env.DEFAULT_BRANCH
                }
            }
            stages {
                stage('Dump env') {

                    steps {
                        sh 'env | sort'
                    }
                }
                stage('Pull code') {
                    steps {
                        container('gitzip') {
                            withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: env.GIT_CREDS, keyFileVariable: 'identityKeyFile')]) {
                                sh "git config core.sshCommand 'ssh -i ${identityKeyFile}'"
                                sh "git submodule update"
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
                stage('Zip code') {
                    steps {
                        container('gitzip') {
                            sh 'git submodule foreach --quiet \'echo $sm_path\' | xargs zip -r fabric-${NEXT_VERSION}'
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage('Push bundle') {
                    steps {
                        container('minio') {
                            sh 'echo mc cp fabric-${NEXT_VERSION} <destination>'
                        }
                    }
                }
                stage('Commit tag') {
                    steps {
                        container('gitzip') {
                            sh "git tag ${env.NEXT_VERSION}"
                            withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: env.GIT_CREDS, keyFileVariable: 'identityKeyFile')]) {
                                sh "git config core.sshCommand 'ssh -i ${identityKeyFile}'"
                                sh 'git push --tags origin'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `git submodule update --init`, to make sure your submodules are initialized when the repository is cloned by Jenkins.

Then a `git submodule --quiet foreach "echo $sm_path"` should print each submodule path, as recorded in the immediate superproject.
Double-check the `pwd` (current execution folder) when running that command.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't do anything. I still got empty output. I ended up just doing `git submodule | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno Sorry, my bad: I suspect using double-quotes would help with variable substitution. I have edited the answer. What version of Git is used on your Jenkins agent?